# how can i manage my api data through states?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-table-v7

hello i'm trying to delete my rows through states and axios request but i'm not sure how can i manage my api data through states, i have to update my table when i delete the row, right now if i log states dont have data to manage

```
import React, {useMemo} from 'react';
import {useSortBy, useTable, usePagination} from 'react-table';
import apiData from '../../../modules/searchCards/apiHooks/apiData.js';
import DeleteModal from '../../../DeleteModal/index.jsx';
import axios from 'axios';
/* eslint-disable react/prop-types */

const useTableResource = () => {
  const {data} = apiData();
  const resourcesData = data;
 
  const resourcesDataLength = resourcesData.length;
  
  // i try to convert my data into useState but is not working i'm not sure why
  const [datas, setData] = React.useState(React.useMemo(() => data, []));

  const resourcesColumns = useMemo(() => [
    {
      id: 'delete',
      accessor: () => 'delete',
      disableSortBy: true,
      Cell: ({row}) => <div onClick={(event) => event.stopPropagation()} style={{
        display: 'flex',
        justifyContent: 'center'
      }}>
        <DeleteModal delb={async (index) => {

        // here should update my data state when i delete
          setData(datas.filter((item, i) => i !== index));

          await axios.delete(`api/resources?_id=${row.original._id}`);
        }}/>

      </div>

    }
  ], []);


  const tableInstance = useTable({
    columns: resourcesColumns,
    data: resourcesData,
    disableSortRemove: true,
  }, useSortBy, usePagination);
   
  return {
    tableInstance,
    resourcesColumns,
    resourcesDataLength
  };
};

export default useTableResource;
```

Comment: i'm using React-table-v7

Comment: Is the issue/error that you are trying to use `useMemo` incorrectly in the `useState` hook? What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I have a component with a table that is loaded with the data sent by the REST API,  my problem is when i delete a row i have to reload the page to update my rows so i'm trying to manage my apiData with useState so i will update my rows with the states

Comment: example https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-surf-iykn7?file=/src/App.js

Comment: i try something like this   `const [datas, setData] = React.useState(apiData);`

Comment: Does `axios.delete(`api/resources?_id=${row.original._id}`)` return anything meaningful, like the table data sans the row you just deleted? What is `apiData`? Is that supposed to be a React hook? What is the source of truth for this table data? You may need to [edit] and provide more context and a more complete [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot going on in the code that's probably not relevant to the question, sounds like the main issue is nothing is being returned once you've deleted a record/item.

Try something like this:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState({});

function getData() {
  axios.get("https://api.example.com")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => setData(data));
}

function deleteItem(id) {
  axios.delete("https://api.example.com/" + id)
    .then(() => getData());
}
```

In this way, after the item has been deleted, you're then calling the api to get the latest update.

In another scenario, it's possible your delete api call is returning the new updated records already, in which case:

```js
function deleteItem(id) {
  axios.delete("https://api.example.com/" + id)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => setData(data));
}
```

Again using example code, but you should be able to go from there.